# Typescript bundle JsTransformer not working

Tags: typescript, bundling-and-minification

I created an MVC Web API project in Visual studio, and I included the Bundle Transformer: Core extension. https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/1.7.21

In my BundleConfig.cs file, I have the following code:

```
var typeScriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ts").IncludeDirectory("~/ViewModels", "*.ts", true);
typeScriptBundle.Transforms.Add(new JsTransformer());
bundles.Add(typeScriptBundle);
```

Now, what this code is supposed to do, is to get all the .ts files in the ViewModels directory, and apply the JsTransformer() to them, and thus give me the .js files I need for references. But this is not happening, I see no references to the .js files that was generated from my type script in my web page when I inspect the html with the Inspector.

Have I made some wrong assumption about how this JsTransformer class is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the ts->Js adaptor before the Jstransformer

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but could you please elaborate, I am very new to Typescript and web technologies in general.

Comment: You need the typescript translator : look at http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/ and download from http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.TypeScript